# Random string generator in c++ returns the same value in loops

Tags: c++, string, random

I have a function that generates *random string* in my program and that works as I want, but only separately from **loops**.
When I use it in loop in main(), it returns the same string every time (let's say 20 for example).
Here is that function:

```
string randomString()
{
string c;
int r = NULL;
int num = 7;
srand(time(NULL));
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    r = rand() % 26;
    c += 'a' + r;   
}
cout << "Random string: " << c << " \n";
return c;
}
```

What should I do to make it return different string every loop?
*Thanks for any help.*

Comment: Only call `srand` ***once*** at the beginning of the program.

Comment: Explanation. srand resets the random number generator each time you call it. That's why you get the same 'random' string each time. Even though you are passing the time to srand, if insufficient time has passed since you last called srand, you're going to get the same random numbers.

Comment: thank you, that is what I was looking for

Comment: a general advice: Read documentation of stuff you are using. `srand`s only purpose is to cause the effect you just saw. This time you got random numbers that are not random, next time it might be something else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the commenters pointed out, `srand()` *sets up* the random number generator, and *seeds* it with it's initial value. As such, it should only be used *once* per program, befor any uses of `rand()`.

In this case, the call to `srand()` should be taken out of `randomString()` and put somewhere before the first call to `rand()`, probably in `main()`.

Answer (score -1):

As this question is tagged with `C++`, I'd recommend to use [std::uniform_int_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution). Together with `mersenne_twister_engine`, it should generate better quality pseudo-random numbers. You can see an example of how to use it at the end of the link.

Comment: This does not answer why the problem occurs in the question. The problem could actually also occur with `std::uniform_int_distribution` and `mersenne_twister_engine` if the same mistake is done as in the question.

Comment: one can make the same mistake also with a better quality prng.

Comment: Agree, will update my answer to reflact that.